# How to display model data using Asp.Net Core ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to access the data of two models (Order andDetailOrder) for the view using a ViewModelOrderProdutoViewModel, but in the view I can only access the data of one model (Order).

Comment: Pls show us what you have done already

Comment: Your ViewModel can contain data from both Order and DetailOrder models, there is nothing to prevent you for doing so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Tuple.

In your action set a returned value to a Tuple:

```
return View(Tuple.Create(Order, DetailOrder));
```

and then, in your view:

```
@{
    @model Tuple<Order, DetailOrder>
}
```